# How to align the equations in latex?

Tags: equations

Below is the code in latex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Ontology}
\begin{split}
    R = \sum_{a_1,b_1=1}^{n_1} ((isSimpleCapabilityOf(SC_a_1, D_b_1) \cup  \sum_{a_2,b_2=1}^{n_2} hasSimpleCapability(D_b_1, SC_a_1)  \cup \sum_{a_3,b_3=1}^{n_3} ConsisitOfSimpleCapability(CC_a_3, SC_b_3) \cup  \sum_{a_4,b_4=1}^{n_4} requiredComCapability(Process_a_4, CC_b_4) ) \cup   \sum_{a_5,b_5=1}^{n_5} IsProcessOf(Pr_a_5, P_b_5) \cup    \sum_{a_6,b_6=1}^{n_6} requiredProcess(P_a_6, Pr_b_6) \sum_{a_7,b_7=1}^{n_7} IsProcessOf(Pr_a_7, P_b_7) \cup requiredProduct(T_a_7, P_b_7))
    
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

How do I auto align the equations? I mean change line automatically.

Comment: line breaking in display math is manual. Or use inline math or the experimental breqn package

Comment: unrelated but `\mathit{ConsisitOfSimpleCapability}` or `\mathrm{ConsisitOfSimpleCapability}` not `ConsisitOfSimpleCapability`  (never use math italic for words)

Comment: `SC_a_1` will produce an error. You probably want `SC_{a1}` or `SC_{a_1}` depending on whether they're two subscripts (like in matrix entries) or the 1 is a subscript to a.

Comment: Off-topic: By placing the entire formula on a single line, you more or less guarantee that you will never be able to look at it sufficiently closely to detect typos and other problems. Moral of the story? Don't be afraid to insert line breaks -- the more, the merrier.

Answer (score 1):

manual choice of line breaking would give a generally better result, but if automatic breaking is a requirement you can use inline math in display style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Ontology}
\parbox{.9\textwidth}{\centering$\displaystyle
  R = \sum_{{a1},{b1}=1}^{n_1} ((\mathrm{isSimpleCapabilityOf}(SC_{a1}, D_{b1}) \cup  
\sum_{a_2,b_2=1}^{n_2} \mathrm{hasSimpleCapability}(D_{b1}, SC_{a1})  \cup 
\sum_{a_3,b_3=1}^{n_3} \mathrm{ConsisitOfSimpleCapability}(CC_{a3}, SC_{b3}) \cup 
 \sum_{a_4,b_4=1}^{n_4} \mathrm{requiredComCapability}(\mathrm[Process]_{a4}, CC_{b4}) ) \cup  
 \sum_{a_5,b_5=1}^{n_5} \mathrm{IsProcessOf}(Pr_{a5}, P_{b5}) \cup 
\sum_{a_6,b_6=1}^{n_6} \mathrm{requiredProcess}(P_{a6}, Pr_{b6}) \sum_{a_7,b_7=1}^{n_7} \mathrm{IsProcessOf}(Pr_{a7}, P_{b7}) \cup 
\mathrm{requiredProduct}(T_{a7}, P_{b7}))
$}    
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to insert explicit line breaks before each `\cup` directive.

I would also change all instances of `\cup` to `{\textstyle\bigcup}`, fix the double-subscript errors, wrap the variable names in `\textnormal` directives, and snug up the `\sum` terms by using `\smashoperator` directives. (`\smashoperator` is a macro that's provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.)

Finally, I can't help but suspect that `ConsisitOfSimpleCapability` should be spelled as `ConsistsOfSimpleCapability`; however, that's not my call to make.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\newcommand\tbc{{\textstyle\bigcup}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:Ontology}
\begin{split}
R = &\smashoperator[l]{\sum_{a_1,b_1=1}^{n_1}} 
     \biggl\{\Bigl[                                            
     \textnormal{isSimpleCapabilityOf}(SC_{a_1}, D_{b_1}) \\
&\tbc\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{a_2,b_2=1}^{n_2}} 
     \textnormal{hasSimpleCapability}(D_{b_1}, SC_{a_1})  \\
&\tbc\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{a_3,b_3=1}^{n_3}} 
     \textnormal{ConsisitOfSimpleCapability}(CC_{a_3}, SC_{b_3}) \\
&\tbc\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{a_4,b_4=1}^{n_4}} 
     \textnormal{requiredComCapability}(\mathit{Process}_{a_4}, CC_{b_4}) 
     \Bigr] \\
&\tbc\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{a_5,b_5=1}^{n_5}} 
     \textnormal{IsProcessOf}(Pr_{a_5}, P_{b_5}) \\
&\tbc\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{a_6,b_6=1}^{n_6}} 
     \textnormal{requiredProcess}(P_{a_6}, Pr_{b_6}) \times
     \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{a_7,b_7=1}^{n_7}} 
     \textnormal{IsProcessOf}(Pr_{a_7}, P_{b_7}) \\
&\tbc\ 
     \textnormal{requiredProduct}(T_{a_7}, P_{b_7})
\smash[t]{\biggr\}}
\smash[b]{\vphantom{\sum_{a_6,b_6=1}^{n_6}}} % assure consistent vertical spacing
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not `\bigcup`, I pray you.

Comment: The two symbols mean different things: `\cup` is binary union, `\bigcup` is N-ary union (to use the ugly Unicode terminology). I really don't understand the meaning of union in that context, but…

Comment: @egreg - I've gone ahead and replaced all instances of `\bigcup` with `{\textstyle\bigcup}`. To my taste, the symbols produced by `\cup` just look way to puny next to the big summation symbols. FWIW, you're in good company: I also don't understand the meaning of the union symbols in the equation at hand either... :-)